# After execution of onclick-callback the 'checked' state is reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onclick, jquery-events

This drives me mad. I just can't understand it.

I wrote a filter-function based on checkboxes and clicking on their labels. I'm checking the 'checked' state of checkboxes and show mathed elements of the list (the rest elements are hidden). I use 3rdparty plugin that stylizes checkboxes (cut from example) and makes checkboxes checked while other `onClick` event does the filtering.

**The problem is that after 'checked' state is successfully set inside a callback-function it "suddenly" becomes reset! I can't understand why that happens.**

I implemented the base logic (without stylizing) here: **http://jsfiddle.net/3Xtuh/13/**
and ask all to help me solve this, please.

Comment: Why are you binding the handler to the label instead of the checkbox? When you click a label, it invokes a click event on the checkbox anyways.

Comment: I believe you are going about this the completely wrong way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In my full implementation the checkboxes themselves are hidden. And stylized images are shown instead of them. The only way to access the checkbox is to click on its label. (i use this plugin: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking the click event manually, and then when your function is done running, the default click event is invoked.

By passing the event variable to your click handler and calling event.preventDefault(); fixes this behavior.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Xtuh/14/

Comment: Essentially, you are manually setting the clicked state, and then after your function is done running - the default HTML action runs and 'unclicks' your checkboxes. Hope this helps.

Comment: Now that isnt to say that it will get you to where you want to be, but at least it might help prod you in the correct direction. You will need some conditions for checking the states after clicking has occurred.

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right about resetting! But could you please give me another hint about triggering the onclick behavior in case of hash contains some elements to check (#ch1&ch2) ?

Comment: What do you mean in case the hash contains elements to check? Do you mean hash elements in the URL?

Comment: I mean - now if i do     $("label[for=" + $(this).attr("id") + "]").trigger('click'); - the onclick event fired twice. But i already resolved this bug. So everything's ok.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `label` will check the associated checkbox even if it´s hidden (using CSS) so there´s no need to reinvent the wheel.

You should use the [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event. Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aWDRE/) and view your console.

Answer (score 0):

It's default browser behavior that's messing your js script. By default, clicking on a label that is either wrapped around checkbox or have valid `for` attribute set, is toggling `checked` state of that checkbox.

You've attached custom onclick handler on labels.

So what's going on is that when clicking on a label? Your click handler gets fired (in in you alter state of target checkbox), and then